# SparkException: Task not serializable (Even after class implements Serializable)

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I'm facing Task not serializable issue, i checked other answer and made my called and calling class `serializable`. my code is like-

```
public class MultiClassification implements Serializable {
   psvm{
   ....
   JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> pairRDD = someRDD.flatMap
            (new GetLabelFeature(.....));
   }
}
```

And GetLabelFeature is like-

```
public class GetLabelFeature extends PMISentimentLexiconBuilder<String> 
    implements FlatMapFunction< String, Tuple2<String, String>> , Serializable {
...
public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(String row) throws Exception {...}
}
```

Also the stack trace here-

```
     06 Oct 2016 12:51:20,307  WARN SerializationDebugger:92 - Exception in serialization debugger
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$ObjectStreamClassMethods$.getObjFieldValues$extension(SerializationDebugger.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1636)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.flatMap(JavaRDDLike.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.flatMap(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at com.infosys.iip.nlp.spark.MultiClassification.main(MultiClassification.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.getObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2050)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1252)
    ... 29 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1636)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.flatMap(JavaRDDLike.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.flatMap(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at com.infosys.iip.nlp.spark.MultiClassification.main(MultiClassification.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.emory.mathcs.nlp.decode.NLPDecoder
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: What part of `java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.emory.mathcs.nlp.decode.NLPDecoder` don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP sorry that was noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `PMISentimentLexiconBuilder`  use `NLPDecoder`? Or maybe your class, `GetLabelFeature`, uses it?

`NLPDecoder` is not serializable, so it cannot be a field of object, that must be serialized.

You have 2 options:

1. Add transient keyword to field with NLPDecoder and init it again after serialization
2. Not use field,  but create NLPDecoder inside function.

I don't know how much time it takes to init NLPDecoder variable, if much time, then use approach number 1. If it is quick, you can use approach number 2, which is simpler